# How do i use button to make the limit become more?

Tags: php, html

What i want to do is use a button to load more message. Now i have set the it limit 40. If user click the load more button than the limit will become 50 , 60 and so on

I no sue how to implement and i look a lot of example still didn't have a clear idea how to do it

Here is my insert.php

```
<?php 

  include '../config.php';
  include'login.php';

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
  $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

  $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO logs(`username`, `msg`,`date`)VALUES('$username', '$msg','$today')");
  $sql1= "SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40
        ) sub
        ORDER BY id ASC";

  mysqli_query ($connection,"delete from logs where date < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");

  $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);

  while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
  $color = ($extract['username'] == $username) ? '  #F5F5F5' : '#DCDCDC';
   $position = ($extract['username'] == $username) ? 'right' : 'left';
  echo "
  <div class='left-wrap-message' style='background-color:$color; float:$position;'>
    <p style='text-align:$position; margin:0;'>". $extract['username']. " : </p>
        <p style='text-align:$position; margin:0; text-align:left;'>  "  . $extract['msg']. "</p></div>
        <div class='msg-dateandtime' style='text-align:$position;'> "  . $extract['date']. "</div>";
    }

?>
```

This is my logs.php

```
<?php 

    include '../config.php';
    include'login.php';

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $sql1= "SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40
            ) sub
            ORDER BY id ASC ";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);

    while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $color = ($extract['username'] == $username) ? '    #F5F5F5' : '#DCDCDC';
     $position = ($extract['username'] == $username) ? 'right' : 'left';

     echo "
     <div class='left-wrap-message' style='background-color:$color; float:$position;'>
     <p style='text-align:$position; margin:0;'>". $extract['username']. "  : </p> 
     <p style='text-align:$position; margin:0; text-align:left;'>  " . $extract['msg']. "</p></div>
      <div class='msg-dateandtime' style='text-align:$position;'> "  . $extract['date']. "</div>";
    }

    ?>﻿
```

This is my html

```
<form name ="chatroom">

<button class="load_more" id="load_more_button">load More</button>
<div class="chatroom-upper-container" id="chatroom-upper-container">
    <div id="inner">
        Loading Message....<img src="../images/loading.gif"/>
    </div>
</div><div class="chatroom-lower-left-container">
    <textarea class="message-setting" id="area-message" placeholder="type text" name= "msg"></textarea>
</div><div class="chatroom-lower-right-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn sendmessage-btn" onclick= "submitChat()">Send</button>
</div>
```

Hope anyone can help me out

Comment: "load more" buttons usually don't increase the limit of the original query, instead they they they fetch a limited result set from the current row to +n. "Load more" and "endless scrolling" are basically just interactive pagination. It's the same implementation, just a different way for the user to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try this.. First bring the number of records in your case it is 40. send a flag with the records if more than 40 records are present.. Now if the flag is on Display the load more button.. and on the click event of the button load 10 more records with the same flag..Append the 10 records in the div in which old 40 records were present. This will till the flag is on when the flag is off you hide the load more button